# Chart.js cut line on annotation

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2, react-chartjs

I'm using react-chartjs2 lib, and I get something like this

[image]

Now I'm wondering if Is there a way to cut blue line on the today annotation line?

Something like this:

[image: https://s15.postimg.cc/zaoj0slyj/image.jpg]

If I just cut data at today annotation, I'll get downfall line and it looks ugly, so that's why I want to do to something like this above

**Any ideas?** Thanks in advance.

Comment: try setting `spanGaps` to false

Comment: @OvidiuDolha it's already set to false :(